# chat using Laravel echo in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, networking, websocket, laravel-echo

I'm working on a chat using `laravel_echo 0.2.2` and pusher.
it's work just fine in debug mode but in the release mode it's doesn't work.

my echo configurations is:

```
echo = new Echo({
  'broadcaster': 'pusher',
  'client': pusherClient,
  "wsHost": 'api.salatkksa.com',
  "httpHost": 'api.salatkksa.com',
  "wsPort": 6001,
  'auth': {
    "headers": {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'}
  },
  'authEndpoint': 'http://api.salatkksa.com/api/broadcasting/auth',
  "disableStats": true,
  "forceTLS": false,
  "enabledTransports": ['ws', 'wss']
});
```

and my pusher configurations:

```
PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
    host: 'api.salatkksa.com',
    port: 6001,
    encrypted: false,
    auth: PusherAuth('http://api.salatkksa.com/api/broadcasting/auth',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'}));
pusherClient = FlutterPusher(
  "468adb0d5808c1",
  options,
  enableLogging: true,
);
```

I just tried to add this to my `androidmanafist.xml` inside the `application` tag:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

so if I add an SSL certificate and use encrypted messaging it will work or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve it by enabling code obfuscation with R8 or proguard, and add the following rule:

in `android/app/build.gradle:`

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
}
```

and if you don't have `proguard-rules.pro` create one in this path `android/app/proguard-rules.pro` and add the following:

```
-keep class com.github.heywhy.flutter_pusher.** { *; }
```

Comment: Can you share some resource to where I can learn more about building a chat system with laravel echo and flutter for an flutter app. Would really appreciate the same :)