# Websockets in Flutter

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, dart, websocket

I'm trying to listen to my Laravel BackEnnd using flutter websockets. There is no documentation about the backend of such a situation and i'm not sure how to go about it. The laravel app seems to work fine when i listen on browser but not on my flutter app.
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets This documentation is just copied by every article on the internet and every youtuber but no realtime implementation

**Current Flutter Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
        channel: IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://192.168.0.164:8000/Message/Socket/123'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.channel})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: widget.channel.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {

            print("XXX : ${snapshot.data}");

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
              child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : ''),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**Laravel Routes**

```
Route::get('/Message/Socket/{message}', [WebSocket_Message::class, 'fetchMessages']);
Route::get('/Message/Socket/Send/{message}', function ($message) {
    broadcast(new MessagePlus_Messages("$message"));
});
```

**JS for Web Implementation** (Works)

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        Echo.channel('Test').listen('MessagePlus_Messages', (e) => {
            
            var date = new Date();
            var now = date.getTime();

            document.write(JSON.stringify(e, null));

            // alert("Receievd");
        });
    </script>
```

When this works on the browser, why isn't it working on my flutter app? It's not an IP related issue as i can use the websockets in my mobile's browser. There just isn't enough documentation and i'm facing a real hard time. Any help is appreciated

Comment: i think you can use this https://pub.dev/packages/laravel_echo#:~:text=Laravel%20Echo%20for%20Flutter,in%20Official%20documentation%20should%20work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939157/chat-using-laravel-echo-in-my-flutter-app  https://nhancv.medium.com/flutter-pusher-with-laravel-echo-7fa7d7929517

Comment: Try to listen websocket stream with `channel.stream.listen(...)` and specified `onError` handler that prints an error. You can add this code to `initState()`. Will it prints out any errors?

Comment: Im using Laravel pusher. Where will i mention the Event and the Channel? It's not adding up @Mol0ko

Comment: @MessagePlus I am talking about Flutter code, you can try to debug connection errors the way I described

Comment: Got me a step further i guess. Error "WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received," Any idea what this may mean? @Mol0ko

Comment: I found this list of possible solutions, take a look https://fluttercorner.com/httpexception-connection-closed-before-full-header-was-received/

Answer (score 0):

To enable insecure connection (http and/or ws://) in Flutter you need this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
```

For IOS you need the following in your plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[Insecure HTTP connections are disabled by default on iOS and Android](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android)